# Django Rest Framework Testing Exceptions In Views

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a test class that inherits from APITestCase. This test class has a test case that attempts to mock a function called to raise an exception by another object in one the views being tested. However, my exception is never getting raised by the mock. If I don't inherit from APITestCase the test cases works as expected essentially.

Does APITestCase hide or prevent exceptions from being propagated up?

Here is my view file:

## views.py

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):        
        pass

class Foo2(object):
    def bar2(self, f):        
        f = Foo()
        f.bar()


class JobListRest(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer

    """
    List all jobs, or create a new job.
    """
    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request, format=None):            
        jobs = Job.objects.all()
        serializer = JobSerializer(jobs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @csrf_exempt
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.bar()

        serializer = JobSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            job = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## test.py

Exception does **NOT** get raised

```
class JobPostTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):        
        self.valid_job = """{
                                'name': 'foo',
                                'tasks':
                                    [
                                        {
                                            'name':'test_task'
                                        }
                                    ]
                            }"""

    @patch('app.views.Foo')
    def test_create_job_fails(self, mock):


        error = ValidationError

        mock.bar.side_effect = error                
        with self.assertRaises(error):
            self.client.post('/api/jobs/', self.valid_job, format='json')
```

Exception **does** get raised

```
class FooTest(TestCase):
    @patch('app.views.Foo')
    def test_bar(self, mock):
        mock.bar.side_effect=ValidationError
        foo2 = Foo2()
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, foo2.bar2(1))
```

Comment: I don't see when you are calling your View from Foo and Foo2 and how exception getting raised in your second scenario. Are you sure this code is the right one?

Comment: That was just to show that the mocking and such was working. Appears I need to mock all the way to function for my test case to work: `@patch('app.views.Foo.bar')`.

Comment: Problem still exists today, as far as I can tell.